# Convert UNION selects to single select with loop in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have this ugly code here in MySQL 8.0.

```
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Adventure'
        group by genre_name, actor_id 
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)        
UNION 
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Music'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Fantasy'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Romance'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Family'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Comedy'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Short'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Animation'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Action'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Horror'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Sci-Fi'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Thriller'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Crime'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Drama'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Documentary'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Musical'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Mystery'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='War'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Western'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Adult'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3)
UNION
(SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id)
       FROM movie_has_genre, role, movie, genre
        where role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
        and genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id
        and genre_name='Film-Noir'
        group by genre_name, actor_id
        ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC
        limit 3);
```

and I want to convert it to be more concise. Basically, the only thing that changes is the genre_name condition. The 21 values for this condition can be found running: `select genre_name from genre;` How can I loop through the 21 values of genre_name and plug them into the select query, incrementally building up the UNION query? Thanks.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @SteliosM . . . *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, STANDARD `JOIN` syntax.  Second, *always* qualify all your column references when a query references more than one table.  How is anyone else supposed to know where the columns come from?

Comment: For few but huge groups a UNION (ALL) query is the most performant and quite simple to create dynamically in the application language. So you might already have he best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL (prior to 8.0), you can use variables for this:

```
select genre_name, actor_id, cnt
from (select genre_name, actor_id, cnt,
             (@rn := if(@g = genre_name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@g := genre_name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select g.genre_name, r.actor_id, count(*) as cnt
            from movie m join
                 role r
                 on r.movie_id = m.movie_id join
                 movie_has_genre mhg
                 on mhg.movie_id = m.movie_id join
                 genre g
                 on g.genre_id = mhg.genre_id
            group by g.genre_name, r.actor_id
            order by g.genre_name, cnt desc
           ) ga cross join
           (select @g := '', @rn := 0) params
      ) ga
where rn <= 3;
```

In 8.0+, use `row_number()` the ANSI standard method for this functionality.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases that the abbreviations for the columns you are using.
- Qualify all column names in the queries that you are using, especially when the `FROM` clause references more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT genre_name, actor_id, count(actor_id) AS cnt
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY genre_name ORDER BY count(actor_id) DESC) rn
  FROM movie
  JOIN movie_has_genre ON movie_has_genre.movie_id=movie.movie_id
  JOIN role            ON role.movie_id=movie.movie_id
  JOIN genre           ON genre.genre_id=movie_has_genre.genre_id  
  group by genre_name, actor_id 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <=3;
```

Please do not use obsolete comma join syntax.

How it works:

- calculate count per genere_name and actor_id
- get 3 most values per genre_name

Comment: MySql does not support ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY

Comment: I think this is close, but the partition shouldn't include actor_id. Per genre, you just want the rows with the highest counts (which are already per actor in the first CTE)

Comment: @PankajKumar Of course it does. [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800)

Comment: @NikShenoy You maybe right. It is more understandable to get COUNT per genre not per (genre/actor).

Comment: No need for the 2nd cte, ROW_NUMBER is calculated *after* aggregation: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY genre_name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn`