# Mysql LOOP with SELECT and UNION

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have got similar issue with my SQL query.
[Convert UNION selects to single select with loop in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541572/convert-union-selects-to-single-select-with-loop-in-mysql)

I have "complicated" SELECT and I UNION ALL SELECTs as in example above.

My question is that maybe it can be done in LOOP?

```
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 30 THEN

      SELECT //my select
      UNION ALL

      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
```

Could you please tell me if it will gonna work in such way? I try to write calendar with periodic events, and I would like to iterate date by date for example 7 days and collect results from SELECTs

Thank you and Regards.

Comment: *" I try to write calendar with periodic events, and I would like to iterate date by date for example 7 days and collect results from SELECTs"*  research calendar tables.

Comment: More or less like [Generating a series of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105018/generating-a-series-of-dates)

Comment: You'll have to insert the results of each iteration's SELECT into a table of some to collect the results together (rather than actually using UNION ALL), and then SELECT from that table after the loop. Doing this in a stored procedure without the aforementioned inserting would just yield multiple result sets.

Comment: Hi I have created DAY table only with ID field, I have filled this table from 1 to 366. Now when I want to 7 days iteration I am doing this:

SET [@]date := '2014-06-26';
SELECT *, [@]date := DATE_ADD([@]date, INTERVAL T.id DAY ) AS it_date

FROM (

MY SELECT how to use [@]date variable? it is always set to '2014-06-26', but in results I can see it is incremented
for example when I write

SELECT EV.*, [@]date I have got the same date '2014-06-26' not incremented but 'it_date' field is incremented

) AS T WHERE T.id <= 7 //For 7 days 
how can use variable in sub select?